# How to prove a polygon to be square using two perpendicular lines?

Tags: geometry

If I had a quadrilateral $ABCD$ and two perpendicular lines one of them bisect $AB$ and $CD$ at a point $E,G$ and the other is perpendicular to the other two sides and intersecting the sides $BC$ at Point $F$ and $BF =BE=AE$. How to prove this quad is an square

Answer (score 1):

Take a trapezoid $ABCD$ with $AB=BC$, $BC||AD$, but $BC\neq AD$.

We see that all our given holds, but $ABCD$ is not square.

Comment: This is image of my question https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHb1b.jpg

Comment: @Momo In your picture it's square, but try to draw the trapezoid, about which I said.

Comment: How did you know that it's a square?

Comment: @Momo  It can be not square.

Comment: It sounds to be a square but I want to prove it with the requirments in the picture

Comment: @Momo It's impossible because there is a counterexample.